# Delete a array value in firebase firestore on android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud Firestore in Android.
How I can delete a value from an array?

I try this but it does not work

```
db.collection("Test")
  .document(Document)
  .collection("array")
  .document("value2")
  .delete();
```

Database:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`FieldValue.arrayRemove()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Something like this in your case:

```
db.collection("Test")
  .document(Document)
  .update("array", FieldValue.arrayRemove("value2"));
```

---

You can also *add* to arrays using `FieldValue.arrayUnion()`. The [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) contains all this information, so check it out.